# How to eliminate Q(x,y) in system of two PDE 

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Analytical problem is simple but I am not sure is it possible in this kind of system. I will give my idea. We can apply on first equation $ \frac{\partial }{\partial x} $ and then that it is possible to substitute from second equation $ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} $ in first, but the problem is that we have Q on two places and coefficient in front is not the same (A and B). A, B, C, D , E and F are constants.

i need one PDE equation just with P(x,y)

$$ -A\frac{\partial ^2Q(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+B\frac{\partial ^3P(x,y)}{\partial x^3}+C Q(x,y)-C\frac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial x}+D\frac{\partial ^2Q(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0 $$

$$ -B\frac{\partial ^3Q(x,y)}{\partial x^3}+E\frac{\partial ^4P(x,y)}{\partial x^4}-C \frac{\partial Q(x,y)}{\partial x}+C\frac{\partial ^2P(x,y)}{\partial x^2}-F\frac{\partial ^2P(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0 $$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-A\frac{\partial^{2}Q}{\partial x^{2}}+B\frac{\partial^{3}P}{\partial x^{3}}+CQ-C\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}+D\frac{\partial^{2}Q}{\partial y^{2}}=0\tag{{1}}$$
$$-B\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x^{3}}+E\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{4}}-C\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}+C\frac{\partial^{2}P}{\partial x^{2}}-F\frac{\partial^{2}P}{\partial y^{2}}=0\tag{{2}}$$

Differentiate $(1)$ with respect to $x$
 :$$-A\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x^{3}}+B\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{4}}+C\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-C\frac{\partial^{2}P}{\partial x^{2}}+D\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x\partial y^{2}}=0\tag{{3}}$$

Add $(2)$ and $(3)$:$$-\left(A+B\right)\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x^{3}}+\left(E+B\right)\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{4}}+D\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x\partial y^{2}}-F\frac{\partial^{2}P}{\partial y^{2}}=0\tag{4}$$
 Differentiate $(2)$ twice with respect to $y$
 :$$-B\frac{\partial^{5}Q}{\partial x^{3}\partial y^{2}}+E\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{4}\partial y^{2}}-C\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x\partial y^{2}}+C\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{2}\partial y^{2}}-F\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial y^{4}}=0\tag{{5}}$$

Differentiate $(4)$ twice with respect to $x$
$$-\left(A+B\right)\frac{\partial^{5}Q}{\partial x^{5}}+\left(E+B\right)\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{6}}+D\frac{\partial^{5}Q}{\partial x^{3}\partial y^{2}}-F\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{2}\partial y^{2}}=0\tag{6}$$

Differentiate $(2)$ twice with respect to $x$
 :$$-B\frac{\partial^{5}Q}{\partial x^{5}}+E\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{6}}-C\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x^{3}}+C\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{4}}-F\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{2}\partial y^{2}}=0\tag{{7}}$$

From $(7)$:

$$\frac{\partial^{5}Q}{\partial x^{5}}=\frac{1}{B}\left(E\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{6}}-C\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x^{3}}+C\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{4}}-F\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{2}\partial y^{2}}\right)\tag{{8}}$$

Substitute into $(6)$: $$-\left(A+B\right)\frac{1}{B}\left(E\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{6}}-C\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x^{3}}+C\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{4}}-F\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{2}\partial y^{2}}\right)+\left(E+B\right)\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{6}}+D\frac{\partial^{5}Q}{\partial x^{3}\partial y^{2}}-F\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{2}\partial y^{2}}=0 \tag{9}$$

From $(5)$ $$\frac{\partial^{5}Q}{\partial x^{3}\partial y^{2}}=\frac{1}{B}\left(E\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{4}\partial y^{2}}-C\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x\partial y^{2}}+C\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{2}\partial y^{2}}-F\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial y^{4}}\right)\tag{10}$$

Substitute into $(9)$: $$-\left(A+B\right)\frac{1}{B}\left(E\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{6}}-C\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x^{3}}+C\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{4}}-F\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{2}\partial y^{2}}\right)+\left(E+B\right)\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{6}}+D\frac{1}{B}\left(E\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{4}\partial y^{2}}-C\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x\partial y^{2}}+C\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{2}\partial y^{2}}-F\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial y^{4}}\right)-F\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{2}\partial y^{2}}=0\tag{11}$$

From $(4)$: $$\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x\partial y^{2}}=-\frac{1}{D}\left(-\left(A+B\right)\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x^{3}}+\left(E+B\right)\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{4}}-F\frac{\partial^{2}P}{\partial y^{2}}\right)\tag{12}$$

Substitute into $(11)$: $$-\left(A+B\right)\frac{1}{B}\left(E\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{6}}-C\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x^{3}}+C\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{4}}-F\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{2}\partial y^{2}}\right)+\left(E+B\right)\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{6}}+D\frac{1}{B}\left(E\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{4}\partial y^{2}}+C\frac{1}{D}\left(-\left(A+B\right)\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x^{3}}+\left(E+B\right)\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{4}}-F\frac{\partial^{2}P}{\partial y^{2}}\right)+C\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{2}\partial y^{2}}-F\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial y^{4}}\right)-F\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{2}\partial y^{2}}=0\tag{13}$$

Differentiate $(1)$ with respect to $x$
  three times:$$-A\frac{\partial^{5}Q}{\partial x^{5}}+B\frac{\partial^{6}P}{\partial x^{6}}+C\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x^{3}}-C\frac{\partial^{4}P}{\partial x^{4}}+D\frac{\partial^{5}Q}{\partial y^{5}}=0\tag{14}$$

$(13)$ gives an expression for $$\frac{\partial^{3}Q}{\partial x^{3}}$$
 . substitution into $(8)$ gives equation for $$\frac{\partial^{5}Q}{\partial x^{5}}$$
 . Substituting the results in $(14)$ gives an equation in terms of P
  and its derivatives only.

Comment: yes, but I need to eliminate Q and all derivatives of function Q, how to do that?

Comment: you just need to solve this linear system (i used the uniform notation $i=0$ corresponds to $Q$)

Comment: @ Valentin Thanks, right answer!

Comment: @ Valentin in second equation should be derivatives x and y?

Comment: yes, you are right i made a slip, so you actually might need to differentiate each a few times more by $x$ and $y$ until the number of equations matches the number of variables

Comment: @ Valentin how many times? Can you write it?

Comment: ok, i am neither Maple, nor Mathematica user at the moment, but this is how i believe it goes

Comment: yes, I need procedure, not in $Mathematica$, general. How to know how many times to make derivatives.

Comment: Yes this is it. Thanks Valentin.

Answer (score 2):

Maple can handle this with **casesplit** in the **PDEtools** package.

> des:= {-A*diff(Q(x,y),x,x)+B*diff(P(x,y),x,x,x)+C*Q(x,y)
>       -C*diff(P(x,y),x)+D*diff(Q(x,y),y,y)=0,
>     -B*diff(Q(x,y),x,x,x)+E*diff(P(x,y),x,x,x,x)-C*diff(Q(x,y),x) 
>       +C*diff(P(x,y),x,x)-F*diff(P(x,y),y,y)=0};
>
> PDEtools:-casesplit(des,[Q,P]);

and the last equation returned is (after some cleaning up)

$$\left( -{B}^{2}+EA \right) {\frac {\partial ^{6}}{\partial {x}^{6}}}P \left( x,y \right) + \left( -  D  C-AF \right) {\frac {
\partial ^{4}}{\partial {y}^{2}\partial {x}^{2}}}P \left( x,y \right) 
+ \left( AC-CE \right) {\frac {\partial ^{4}}{\partial {x}^{4}}}P
 \left( x,y \right) +  D  F{\frac {\partial ^{4}}{
\partial {y}^{4}}}P \left( x,y \right) -  D E   {
\frac {\partial ^{6}}{\partial {y}^{2}\partial {x}^{4}}}P \left( x,y
 \right)   +CF{\frac {\partial ^{2}}{\partial {y}^{2}}}P
 \left( x,y \right) = 0
$$

Comment: @ Robert Israel Is it possible to do this in $Mathematica$?

Comment: @George: I'm not a Mathematica user, so I don't know.